# How to map MySql built-in function TIMESTAMPDIFF in EF Core?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, custom-function

I used this, but it put the unit in a quote like 'MONTH'; how can I force him not to generate it without a quote?

```cs
    [DbFunction("TIMESTAMPDIFF", IsBuiltIn = true)]
    public static int DateDiffMinute([NotParameterized] string unit, DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        throw new Exception("Should not be called!");
    }
```

Comment: That's already mapped in the most common EF Core provider for MySQL, [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql). Oracle's provider is not well maintained and lacks a lot of features, which is why Pomelo has 37M downloads compared to Oracle's 2M

Comment: Better to use `Pomelo` driver as mentioned before. It is less buggy than official driver and natively supports async operations.

Comment: I tried Pomelo, but the problem is that I use both SQL Server and MySql in the same project, and Promelo has some conflict with it when both are added to the same project.

Comment: It Is know EF Core design decision. In one project you should use only one provider.

Comment: What conflict? Why not solve the conflict instead of assuming you have to double-map the function? Pomelo isn't EF itself, it's the EF provider you specified in `AddDbContext` or `OnConfiguring`. EF isolates the rest of the application from provider differences, unless you try to use database-specific functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define translation for this function. Also `unit` parameter should be removed.

Assuming that your function is defined in static class `MySQLFunctions`

```cs
public static class MySQLFunctions
{
    public static int DateDiffMinute(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Should not be called!");
    }
}
```

In `OnModelCreating` define translation of this function:

```cs
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => MySQLFunctions.DateDiffMinute(default, default))
    .IsBuiltIn()
    .HasTranslation(parameters =>
        new SqlFunctionExpression("TIMESTAMPDIFF", parameters.Prepend(new SqlFragmentExpression("MINUTE")),
            true, new[]{false, true, true}, typeof(int), null));
```

Answer (score 1):

That's [already mapped](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/wiki/Translations#datediff-functions) in the most popular (and truly open source) EF Core provider, [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql). You can use `EF.Functions.DateDiffMonth(startDate, endDate)` directly.

The Pomelo provider uses the also open source [MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net/) provider instead of Oracle's Connector/.NET. The [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) and [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) packages  solve many of the issues found in Oracle's drivers and add many features that don't exist in the Oracle drivers and providers. They're updated more frequently than Oracle's own packages and by now are both more popular than Oracle's packages.

If you check [NuGet statistics](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=mysql) you'll see :

- MySqlConnector **61M** downloads
- MySQL.Data (Oracle) **57M**

The EF Core provider situation is more dramatic:

- Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql **37M**
- MySql.EntityFrameworkCore (Oracle) **2M**

**Avoiding Conflicts**

If different providers are used in the same project, the compiler may not know which method to use and generate `CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:`. This can be resolved in several ways and the IDE probably already proposes one of them as a fix :

- The method can be called normally
- A [using static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#static-modifier) import can be used to "separate" the names

In the following example a static import is used to allow calling the MySQL function directly, as if it was a normal function:

```
using static Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MySqlDbFunctionsExtensions;

...

var totalDuration=dbContext.Events.Sum(e=>DateDiffMinute(e.Start,e.End));
```

Comment: I tried Pomelo, but the problem is that I use both SQL Server and MySql in the same project, and Promelo has some conflict with it when both are added to the same project. I think I have to separate their repo into different libraries to overcome this conflict, but it is just one call, and it doesn't worth it yet.

Comment: @MohammadNikravan what conflicts? Why not solve them?

Comment: Error CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions.DateDiffSecond(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbFunctions, System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' and 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MySqlDbFunctionsExtensions.DateDiffSecond(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbFunctions, System.DateTime, System.DateTime)'

Comment: You can solve that by either calling the method as a normal method(not as an extension) , using static imports  (`using static Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MySqlDbFunctionsExtensions` then `DateDiffSecond(x.Start,x.End)`) or a using alias directive, eg `using TheExtensions = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MySqlDbFunctionsExtensions;`. Your IDE probably offers one of these as a fix for the error already

Comment: @MohammadNikravan I added an example that uses static imports to solve the conflict